# Is it ok to edit questions only to bump them to the top of the list?

Tags: discussion, editing

I just stumbled over this edit:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/98434/revisions

While I'm confident the edit was done with good intents, it feels a bit like an abuse of the site's mechanics.

**Is editing questions only to bump them to the top of the 'active questions' list accepted practice?**

I am not sure how meta.programmers.SE relates to meta.stackoverflow, but there's a quite [similiar question regarding SO questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53012/what-is-the-best-way-to-bump-re-ask-an-old-question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *edit: gratuitous bump to front page*

This is definitely frowned upon.

If you must edit, edit in the spirit of the faq: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

> To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. **Edit your question to provide status and progress updates.** Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question and get more people interested in it.

Don't just add noise, add signal!

Answer (score 1):

I certainly appreciate your concern, and yes I can assure you that it was done in all honesty. I will do my best in the future to add "signal, not noise" to the thread.  My problem was, and is that it's kind of a static situation.  I'm not actively pursuing an alternative solution at this time, I'm just seeking input on whether the method we are currently using is right, wrong or indifferent...so I don't really have any status or progress updates. Adding a bounty was new to me, I wasn't aware that was an intended purpose of a bounty (yes, I should read the FAQ better), so that was good info to find out.